# tsconfig vscode error vite for vuejs + typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite

is anyone ever got this error before ?

[image]

this error always appear after installing new library like vue router, vuex etc

here is my tsconfig.json config file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ]
}
```

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

it doesn't throw any error every time i run command "npm run serve" in terminal, but kinda annoying since it's showing error in vscode.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.